# Can't get res.render(...) to work properly

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, routes

I'm using nodejs and express. In my 'routes.js':

```
app.get('/', function(req, res) {
    res.render('index.ejs', {
        message : ''
    });
});

app.get('/vote', function(req, res) {
    res.send('Access denied.');
});

app.post('/', function(req, res){
    var server = require('../server');
    var code = req.body.access.code;

    var index = server.validate(code);
    if(index >= 0) {
        console.log('Login with index: ' + (index+1));
        if(server.questionExists()) {
            var parameters = server.getQuestionParameters();
            console.log(parameters[1].length);
            res.render('vote.ejs', { accessCode : code, question: parameters[0], answers: parameters[1], numberOfRequired: parameters[2], vacantIndex: parameters[3], blankIndex: parameters[4]});
        } else
            res.render('vote.ejs', { accessCode : code, question: null, answers: null, numberOfRequired: null, vacantIndex: -1, blankIndex: -1});
    } else
        res.render('index.ejs', {
            message : 'Invalid access code.'
        });
});

app.post('/vote', function(req, res) {
    var server = require('../server');
    var code = req.body.accessCode;
    var answers = req.body.answers;

    for(var i = 0; i < answers.length; i++)
        console.log('a: ' + answers[i]);

    if(server.validate(code) >= 0) {
        if(server.codeAnsweredQuestion(code))
            res.end('anweredError');
        else if(server.validAnswers(answers)) {
            server.register(code, answers);
            res.end('success'); 
        } else
            res.end('corruptError');
    } else
        res.render('index.ejs', {
            message : 'Invalid access code.'
        });
});
```

If we look at the else-part in the post request:

```
    } else
        res.render('index.ejs', {
            message : 'Invalid access code.'
        });
```

Which is identical in the '/' post and in the '/vote' post.

This part always works when doing a post requests to '/', but it does nothing when doing a post request to '/vote'. It gives no errors either on the server side or to the frond end.

I've tested and made sure that the code is reached by the program.

**EDIT**

Could it have anything to do with how I am raising the post events?

The '/' post request is raised via a form:

```
<form action='/' method='post'>
    ...
</form
```

The '/vote' post request is raised via jquery:

```
$.post('vote', { accessCode: code, answers: givenAnswers}, function(returnedData){
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm wondering if the problem is with the field you're accessing from the req.body for the access code value. In the POST to / your code is: `var code = req.body.access.code;` but in the POST to /vote it is `var code = req.body.accessCode;`

Try logging `server.validate(code)` in both POST / and POST /vote and see if you're getting the expected result in both cases. It's difficult to say more without knowing what's happening in ../server.js and `server.validate(code)`

Comment: I was just inconsistent with the variable names. After both have been changed to accessCode the problem still remains.

Comment: I think maybe there's not enough context here to provide you a sussinct answer. One though I've had: in your ajax post method, change `$.post('vote'`, to `$.post('/vote',` Then, could you elaborate on what *is* returned when you POST to the /vote endpoint? Nothing at all?

Comment: After investigating this issue further I decided to start a new question that is more specific: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29212414/express-render-redirect-does-not-work-if-the-call-isnt-coming-from-a-submit-me