# Express' render/redirect does not work if the call isn't coming from a submit method in a form

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, ejs, body-parser

### Task

Perform a POST request from a JS method, so that variable values can be sent as parameters.

### Environment

- NodeJS
- Express
- BodyParser
- ejs

### My first attempt

**Frontend:**

```
<html>
    <head>
        <script src='http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.2/jquery.min.js'></script>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            function postAnswer() {
                $.post('vote', { message: "hello!"}, function(returnedData) {
                    console.log("Post returned data: " + returnedData);
                });
            }
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <button id='send' onClick='postAnswer()' class='btn btn-success btn-xs'>Svara</button>
    </body>
</html>
```

**Server.js:**

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');

app.use(bodyParser());

require('./app/routes.js')(app);

app.set('view engine', 'ejs');
app.use('/public', express.static(__dirname + '/public'));

var server = require('http').createServer(app);
server.listen(8080);
console.log('Server running on port 8080...');
```

**routes.js:**

```
module.exports = function(app) {
    app.get('/', function(req, res) {
        res.render('vote.ejs', {
            message: ''
        });
    });

    app.post('/vote', function(req, res) {
        var msg = req.body.message;
        console.log("Got POST request with message: " + msg);
        res.render('index.ejs', {
            message: ''
        });
    });
};
```

### Result:

The render method won't render a new page. It will however return the entire 'index.ejs' file in the *returnedData* parameter.

**Server:**

[image: server result]

**Client:**

[image: frontend result]

### Second attempt:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <script src='http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.2/jquery.min.js'></script>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            function postAnswer() {
                $.post('vote', { message: "hello!"}, function(returnedData) {
                    console.log("Post returned data: " + returnedData);
                });
                return false;
            }
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <form action='/vote' method='post'>
            <button id='send' type='submit' onsubmit='return postAnswer()' class='btn btn-success btn-xs'>Svara</button>
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

### Result:

This does work, but it's not a very clean solution.

### My questions:

1. Why doesn't the first attempt work?
2. How can I send variables as parameters to a POST request with a nice clean solution?

Comment: FYI, using the catch-all `bodyParser()` like that is deprecated: you should be using `bodyParser.urlencoded({extended: false})` and/or `bodyParser.json()`, depending on whether your app/route handles HTML forms or JSON API calls, respectively. (And one of the modules listed [here](https://github.com/expressjs/body-parser#readme) if it's meant to handle uploads.)

Comment: Also, if you're just starting out with HTML and the browser, I would strongly recommend that you don't use jQuery, and instead learn the DOM by familiarizing yourself with the actual native interfaces that abstractions like jQuery wrap. (For places where the native interface is a little hoary, like XmlHttpRequest, I suggest finding a lightweight wrapper for that specific interface, or using a polyfill for a future cleaner standard, such as (in this specific instance) the [`window.fetch`](https://github.com/github/fetch) function.

Comment: Thanks for some great answers and tips. Much appreciated! :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not a jQuery expert, but I think the first attempt doesn't work because `$.post` makes an AJAX request, the same way as you would in a single-page app to interact with an API in the background.

Your second example submits a form, which is an in-browser action that performs a navigation action (as specified by the `method` attribute of the form). In this case, the event listener you add in jQuery is redundant, and should be removed - it's making *another* background `POST` request, before the form submits the content of its fields in *its* request.

As for your second question, the way to submit additional variables with a form submission (presuming that you actually want to do a navigating form submission and not an XHR background request against an API) is to use `<input type="hidden">` elements.

So, to summarize, to do what you're describing in your question, your example HTML should look like this (minus the comments):

```html
<!DOCTYPE html> <!-- only you can prevent quirks mode -->
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8"> <!-- ༼ つ ◕_◕ ༽つ Give UNICODE -->
  </head>
  <body>
    <form action='/vote' method='post'>
      <input type="hidden" name="message" value="hello!">
      <button id='send' type='submit' class='btn btn-success btn-xs'>Svara</button>
    </form>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Is it considered a good solution to use hidden DOM objects to pass states?

Comment: If you're submitting HTML forms, yes, it's the *only* solution. It's what the "hidden" input type was made for: form properties that are not meant to be filled by the user.

Comment: What if I don't want to submit an form, but only variable values?

Comment: If you want to only submit variable values (ie. no user-input fields), just make a form that only has `<input type="hidden">` elements.

Comment: This is assuming you want the form submission behavior, where you navigate to a new page with the response from a POST (with the "Resubmitting this form could cause something you don't want" warning and everything).

Comment: If you just want to submit variables to an API and get *arbitrary content* (not a page) back, you can use XHR/fetch (or jQuery's wrappers around them like $.post and $.ajax) and listen for the response in a callback. On the server side for API endpoints like this, you would pass the content you want to respond with as a string to `res.send()`, or an arbitrary value to `res.json()`, instead of using `res.render()`.

Comment: Which approach you should go with depends on what kind of app you're writing: an app that just takes simple form input and processes it should use plain-old HTML forms and an `app.post()` route that ends with a `res.redirect()` to a page on an `app.get()` route (so the user can bookmark it and everything else they traditionally expect about how the web behaves). On the other hand, an app that needs to process things on the server while *staying open and doing more things on the same page* should use a JSON-based API.