# Res.render() not rendering

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I have this express route that seems to be refusing to render a jade template. When I put the wrong jade template string in, I get the usual couldn't find the fie being rendered to the browser.

But when I have the right one in, nothing happens...

Also, when I put a `res.status(500).send()` AFTER the `res.render()`, I end up getting the 500 error or any other code I choose to put in there.

What's going on here?

```js
 app.post('/stuff/new', function (req,res){


    Stuff.findById(req.body.booking_id, function(err, stuff){
      if(err){ console.log("Err", err)}

      else if (booking) {

        Thungs.findById(req.body.user_id, function(err, thung){
          user.stuff.push(req.body.things);
          user.save();
        });

        Thingers.findById(req.body.center_id, function(err, thinger){
          center.stuff.push(req.body.things);
          center.save();
        });

        stuff.prop = 'thing';
        stuff.save(function(err, result){
          if (err) { console.err("err", err) }
          else {

            res.render('booking/thank_you', {
              url: req.url,
              id: "thank_you"
            }, function(err, html){
              if (err) { console.err("ERR", err) }
              else {
                res.send(html);
              }
            });
            res.status(500).send();

          }
        });
      }
    })
  });
```

Comment: Could this be because I am using $.ajax to call this route?

Comment: did you set express to use jade?

Comment: Can you check the chrome-dev tools to check the response from the server? (remove the `res.status(500)...` first). Also, are you getting errors shown in your console?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Express' render/redirect does not work if the call isn't coming from a submit method in a form](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29212414/express-render-redirect-does-not-work-if-the-call-isnt-coming-from-a-submit-me)

Answer (score 0):

You dont need `res.send(html);` if you jsut want to  render template, just remove the call back from `res.render()` it should work fine. and also when `res.status(500).send();` is showing 500 becuase the connection does not terminate after `res.render()` and `res.send()` the statements following them will execute, you can user `return res.render()` and `return res.send()` then control will not go to `res.status(500).send()`

hope it helps :)

Comment: I'm not sure what you're talking about, res.status(500).send() is showing 500 because I put 500 in there

Answer (score 0):

The entire `stuff.save()` callback is incorrect because you're never returning the result of `res.render()`. Your `res.render()` gets executed however, since you're passing a callback to `res.render()` it will not automatically respond to the request.

> #### [res.render(view [, locals] [, callback])](http://expressjs.com/en/api.html#res.render)
>
> *Renders a view and sends the rendered HTML string to the client. Optional parameters:*
>
> - **locals**, an object whose properties define local variables for the view.
> - **callback**, a callback function. If provided, the method returns both the possible error and rendered string, but does not perform an automated response. When an error occurs, the method invokes next(err) internally.

Since the `res.render()` function isn't blocking, your `stuff.save()` callback continues execution to `res.status(500).send()` and responds. Ultimately your view doesn't get rendered and your left getting a 500 Internal Server Error as a response.

Its important to note that it is a "best practice" in almost all scenarios to `return` when doing a response where you want to stop execution after responding. The only time you wouldn't want to use a `return` when responding is if you need to do some type of cleanup routine afterwards.

The below code correctly returns `res.render()` when successful and `res.status(500)` in the event of an error.

```
stuff.save(function(err, result){
  if (err) { 
    console.err("err", err) 

    // An error occurred, stop execution and return 500
    return res.status(500).send();
  } 

  // No error occurred, attempt to render the view 
  // and return the outcome of the rendering to the callback
  res.render('booking/thank_you', {
      url: req.url,
      id: "thank_you"
    }, function(err, html){
      if (err) { 
        console.err("ERR", err) 

        // An error occurred, stop execution and return 500
        return res.status(500).send();
      }

      // Return the HTML of the View
      return res.send(html);
    });
  }
});
```

Comment: Works fine on all the other routes

Comment: Did you try my suggestion?

Answer (score 0):

this could also result into error if you are using ajax in your html page and you have to send data as json format.